# Trouble connecting Logstash with Kafka using SSL and schema registry (all dockerized)

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, logstash, avro

I have prepared a logstash pipeline that reads from an internal kafka cluster, and then write on an external one. If I use codec json and SSL certs, everything works perfectly. However, I need to use schema registry (codec avro_schema_registry) for compliance reasons. If I implement a kafka producer with python, I do not have any issue. When I try and add it to my pipeline, tho, logstash shuts down with the following error:

**error=>"(SSLError) Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints"**

The certificates and keys look fine (RSA key 4096 bit + SHA256 ) so I don't know where this is coming from. My pipeline if it helps

```
input {
  kafka {
    codec => json
    bootstrap_servers => "kafka:9093"
    topics => ["test_alert"]
    auto_offset_reset => "earliest"
    group_id => "new"
  }
}

filter {   
    prune {
        whitelist_names => ["id", "from", "to", "subject"]
    }
}


output {
  # internal cluster for test purpose
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "kafka:9093"
    topic_id => 'test_mess'
    codec => json
    message_key => "siem_msg"
  }
  # external cluster
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "******"
    topic_id => '***'
    message_key => "***"
    ssl_keystore_location => "/certs/***.ks.jks"
    ssl_keystore_password => "***"
    ssl_truststore_location => "/certs/***.ts.jks"
    ssl_truststore_password => "***"
    security_protocol => "SSL"
    codec => avro_schema_registry {
      endpoint => "https://kafka-registry.***:8085"
      schema_id => 47
      client_key          => "/certs/***.pem"
      client_certificate  => "/certs/***.pem"
      ca_certificate      => "/certs/***.pem"
      verify_mode         => "verify_peer"
    }
    value_serializer => "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer"
  }

  stdout {
    codec => json
  }
}
```

I tried checking the logstash java.security file to check the constraint. The constraint should not affect my certificates, as mentioned before. I am not the owner of the cluster so I can't generate new certificates or anything. The avro plugin is also correctly installed. Some lines from the java.security file that might be involved with the issue, even tho commenting them out didn't seem to affect the result:

```
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, SHA1 jdkCA & usage TLSServer, \
    RSA keySize < 1024, DSA keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, \
    SHA1 usage SignedJAR & denyAfter 2019-01-01

jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 1024, \
      DSA keySize < 1024, SHA1 denyAfter 2019-01-01

jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
    DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL
```